# Can't send text(string) from ttcpserver to ttcpclientserver

Tags: delphi, ttcpserver

I have 2 forms, 1 for server another for client.
After dropping ttcpserver on server form and setting its localhost property to 127.0.0.1 and localport property to 55555 and Active property to true I wrote a button1(sendtextbutton) onclick event handler:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      TcpServer1.Sendln('message');
end;
```

Then on client form I dropped 1 ttcpclient 1 label 2 buttons, set clients remote host property to 127.0.0.1 and remote port to 55555, wrote an event handler for connectbutton(button1):

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
try
TcpClient1.Active := true;
except
showmessage('error');

end;
end;
```

Wrote an onconnect event for ttcpclient:

```
procedure TForm2.TcpClient1Connect(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Caption := 'connected!';
end;
```

and then finally an onrecieve event hadler for ttcpclient:

```
procedure TForm2.TcpClient1Receive(Sender: TObject; Buf: PAnsiChar;
  var DataLen: Integer);
begin
    Label1.caption := TcpClient1.Receiveln();
end;
```

My client programs caption was supposed to change to 'message'(after I connect and click button on my server form), but it doest. Am I doing it the wrong way? If yes, then how to do it? I am trying to send a text message from server to client(Yes a reverse connection!)

Comment: Your server is not talking to the client socket. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591256/delphi-ttcpserver-connection-reset-when-reading

Comment: @ mjustin: but my clients label caption turns to connected witch means i am connected :(

Comment: The client is connected, but the server can only send to it using the right socket. How can `TcpServer1.Sendln()` know which client should receive the data (there can be many clients connected at the same time)? See my link, it uses `ClientSocket.Sendln` on the server side. I can also recommend Internet Direct (Indy) - you will find more code examples for it.

Comment: i dont understand how will ClientSocket.Sendln on the server side know which client to send to i mean should'nt it be something like clientsocket1.sendln ,clientsocket2.sendln ,and i find indy hard to understand and use is there a good alternative to indy?

Comment: On the server side, each client will have its own `TCustomIpClient` object.  That object is provided to you in the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event.  Depending on how you are using `TTcpServer` (ie, if you are using the default settings), that is the ONLY place you can access the client's `TCustomIpClient` object from.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TTcpServer does not store a list of connected connection which make broadcast style messages difficult.

I would recommend switching to TidTcpServer and TidTcpClient.  The TidTcpServer component has a Context Property that you can loop through to broadcast messages to the clients similar to what you seem to want to do.

Here some links to examples of using TidTcpServer and TIdTcpClient:

- [Exchanging Data over the Network using Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa020403a.htm)
- [Get Image from Client with Indy Socket](http://exampledelphi.com/delphi.php/socket/get-image-from-server-with-indy-socket/)
- [New and Improved Screen Thief 2](http://delphi.about.com/od/indy/ss/screen_thief2.htm)
- [Indy Demo's Downloads'](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx)

Comment: no i do not want to broadcast my message just send it from a single server to a single client is tidtcpserver/tidtcpclient good for that too?

Comment: If you have only one client on your server will still benefit from using the Indy Components.     But using TTcpServer component you would have to do the Sendln in the OnAccept() event.

Comment: is onaccept event fired whenever server is connected to the  client?

Comment: It should be fired on connect

Comment: but cant i send sendln from button1click or something ....is there a way to do this?

Comment: also can you point to an example of doing this using any compnent indy,ttcpserver,tserversocket please help i cant make this program

Comment: all of these example teach you how to send it from client to server do you know of an example that teaches you to send it from server to client and i think indy is HARD to understand or use(maybe only for bigginers) is there a good alternative to indy,do u have any example based on tserversocket/tclientsocket or ttcpserver/ttcpclientserver,thanks for your help

Comment: No examples with TTcpServer and/or TTCPClientServer

Comment: is there a free component in jedi vcl(or any other component that your aware of) or or is there a free unit (that your aware of) than can make my task possible? thanks again for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Your server code does not work because `TTcpServer.SendLn()` does not send the data to the client's endpoint of the connected socket.  That is why the client never sees the data - it is being sent into limbo.

If the `TTcpServer.BlockMode` property is set to `bmThreadBlocking` (which it is by default), or if the `TTcpServer.BlockMode` is set to anything else and you are manually calliing the parameterless overloaded `TTcpServer.Accept()` method, then the only place you have access to the client's endpoint is from inside the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event.  Under these conditions, when that event handler exits, the server will disconnect the client, so any work the server wants to do with the client must be done from inside that event.

If that does not suit your needs, then you will have to set the `TTcpServer.BlockMode` property to either `bmBlocking` or `bmNonBlocking` and then manually call the overloaded `TTcpServer.Accept()` method that returns a `TCustomIpClient` object.  After the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event has been triggered and exited, you will gain ownership of that object and have full control over its lifetime and can then access it whenever and however you want.